# <sj:dialog /> giving stackoverflow javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

I am using struts2 dialog. The code is as below

```
<sj:dialog id="orderRefDialog" 
        width="610" 
     autoOpen="false" 
        modal="true" 
    resizable="false" 
        title="Confirm"  
       height="auto"
      buttons="{'OK':function() {
                      $(this).dialog('close');
                      performShipBox();
                },
                'CANCEL':function() { 
                      $(this).dialog('close'); 
                      cancelShipbox();  
                }
               }">

    <fmt:message key='orderRef.ShipBox'  />

</sj:dialog>
```

When the dialog is open and any button on dialog is clicked it is giving javascript error

```
 Stack OverFlow at line:1648
```

If I remove `model=true` this error does not occur, but I dont think it's a good way.

What can it be ?

Comment: @AleksandrM M  After removing both the functions also its having same issue. And the version is struts2-jquery-3.3.0.

Comment: 3.3.0 is very old version - https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/releases. Try to upgrade.

Comment: @AleksandrM cant we fix the bug in this version 3.3.0 only.

Comment: And my you can try to avoid using $(this).dialog('close');
Better use close topics instead.